# Can we delete the crystal tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are currently 10 questions tagged [crystal](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystal), which are all also tagged [crystalline-structure](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystalline-structure). In that case it does not make any sense to me to keep the former at all (not even as a synonym).

Secondly I would like to suggest to rename crystalline-structure to crystal structure. A simple [google fight](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=%22crystalline%20structure%22&word2=%22crystal%20structure%22) reveals, that the latter is much more common.

Comment: Agree on both counts. I'll merge if nobody disagrees.

Comment: @ManishEarth Fine with me as well. :)

Comment: *vigorously knocks on table* -- *(chants)* Yes we can! Yes we can!

Comment: @jonsca This request is quite old now, shall we do it, there were no opponents so far.

Comment: @Martin So it is written. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We now have [crystal-structure](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystal-structure).

[crystal](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystal) and [crystalline-structure](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystalline-structure) are now synonyms of [crystal-structure](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystal-structure).